# How do I access functions in a third party source file?

Tags: c++, math, linker, numbers

I was looking for an algorithm that would enable me to use the mathematical Bessel function for complex numbers. Now I have found [a promising result](http://www.crbond.com/math.htm#Bessel%20Functions). (I'm interested in *Bessel functions Jv and Yv for real or complex arguments and real order*.)

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 Express C++ and now I want to get access to those functions implemented there. How do I do that?

Comment: Add the .cpp and .h files into your vcproj using the "Add Item..." interface from Visual Studio (right-click your project in the solution explorer and select Add Item...). Likely you will just copy the source files to your main project file source directory first, then do the add. They don't look particularly odd to configure beyond that. The online help for VS is excellent. Search for Add exiting items to a project."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this http://www.crbond.com/download/bessel.zip file and add the files to your visual studio project. To use the functions, you will need to `#include "BESSEL.h"` to your source file.

I got it compile on Visual Studio by doing the following

1. Adding `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` to preprocessor definitions.
2. Changing `#include <complex.h>` to `#include <complex>`
3. Adding `using namespace std;` to `BESSEL.H`

Example of how to call a function:

```
#include "BESSEL.H"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double x, i0, i1, k0, k1, i0p, i1p, k0p, k1p;
    x = 5.0;
    i0 = 1.0;
    i1 = 2.0;
    k0 = 3.0;
    k1 = 4.0;
    i0p = 5.0;
    i1p = 6.0;
    k0p = 7.0;
    k1p = 8.0;

    bessik01a(x, i0, i1, k0, k1, i0p, i1p, k0p, k1p);
    // Results are stored in the variables i0..k1p
    cout << i0 << " " << i1 << " " << k0 << " " << k1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why capital spelling of BESSEL in BESSEL.h. by the way, it does not work. did you check it by yourself?

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked, but unfortunately in the program that you recommended to download, I do not see how my functions are called, so if you can give me an example code, how to get the value of just ONE of those bessel functions, I will award a 100 points bounty to you :-)

Comment: I added an example of how to call one of the functions. I'm not sure what the parameters mean or what the return values mean. You might have to take that question to a math forum.

Comment: @XinWang did you manage to understand the meaning of every parameter to call the function? I would like to use this same library, but I don't know the usage of the calling arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Add the files linked above to your project:

[image: Solution]

Note you have to edit out old header files in these .cpp files and .h file. More specific:
change

```
#include<complex.h>
```

to

```
#include<complex>
```

and use namespace std. Also for `math.h`.
In main.cpp as in picture above write:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "BESSEL.H"

int main ()
{
    complex<double> z = 3;
    complex<double>  J0;
    complex<double>  J1;
    complex<double>  Y0;
    complex<double>  Y1;
    complex<double> J0p;
    complex<double> J1p;
    complex<double> Y0p;
    complex<double> Y1p;

    cbessjy01(z,J0,J1,Y0,Y1,J0p,J1p,Y0p,Y1p);

    cout<< "J0:  " << J0  << "\n";
    cout<< "J0p: " << J0p << "\n";
    cout<< "J1:  " << J1  << "\n";
    cout<< "J1p: " << J1p << "\n";
    cout<< "Y0:  " << Y0  << "\n";
    cout<< "Y0p: " << Y0p << "\n";
    cout<< "Y1:  " << Y1  << "\n";
    cout<< "Y1p: " << Y1p << "\n";

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Try to run the program. `z` is the argument for the bessel function.

You may ask what are `J0`, `J1`, etc they are the Bessel functions but if you need to detremine which is which try a numerical value in the formulas you have. for example check J0 is the result of which formula. I'm not an expert in Bessel functions. But if you give me the exact formulas you need to use I can test.